# Selecting portion of column name for panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have more than 200 columns, each with long names and I want to remove the first part of the names, how do I do that using pandas?

Comment: could you clarify what the first part is?

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through them and omit the first `n` characters:

```
n = 3
li = []
for col in df.columns:
    col = col[n:]
    li.append(col)
df.columns = li
```

Or perform any other form of string manipulation, I'm not sure what you mean by "to remove the first part".

Answer (score 0):

Use indexing with `str`:

```
 N = 5
 df.columns = df.columns.str[N:]
```

Comment: Would this not remove the last part of a string, whereas OP is asking to remove the first part of a string? I think you mean `[N:]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
n=5
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x[n:])
```

and here, the lambda can be anything, you could also strip further whitespace, and actually, you can just define a callable and use with here, potentially without even using `lambda`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove a certain number of characters:

```
df.rename(columns=lambda col: col[n:])
```

If you want to selectively remove based on a prefix:

```
# cols = 'a_A', 'a_B', 'b_A'
df.rename(columns=lambda col: col.split('a_')[1] if 'a_' in col else col)
```

How complicated your rules are is up to you.